Why AlibabaPuHuiTi can match Sans-serif and serif at the same time?
Install a font family- AlibabaPuHuiTi:
wget  https://puhuiti.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/AlibabaPuHuiTi-3.zip
sudo mkdir -p  /usr/share/fonts/alibaba
unzip AlibabaPuHuiTi-3.zip
sudo cp -R  AlibabaPuHuiTi-3  /usr/share/fonts/alibaba 
sudo chmod  -R  755  /usr/share/fonts/alibaba
cd /usr/share/fonts/alibaba
sudo mkfontdir
sudo mkfontscale
sudo fc-cache -fv

AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-RegularL3.otf can match sans-serif：
fc-match -s sans-serif:lang=zh | grep Alibaba
AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-RegularL3.otf: "Alibaba PuHuiTi 3.0" "55 Regular L3"

AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-RegularL3.otf can match serif:
fc-match -s serif:lang=zh | grep Alibaba
AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-Regular.otf: "Alibaba PuHuiTi 3.0" "55 Regular"
AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-RegularL3.otf: "Alibaba PuHuiTi 3.0" "55 Regular L3"

Why AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-RegularL3.otf can match serif  and sans-serif at the same time?
